# How to configure tsserver with nvim lspconfig?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I'm trying to configure tsserver via neovim lspconfig. Currently I am trying to enable logging to verbose mode:

```lua
lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  root_dir = lspconfig.util.root_pattern ".git",
  settings = {
    typescript = {
      tsserver = {
        enableTracing = true,
        log = "verbose",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

When I run `:LspLog` I do not see any logs from tsserver. Is my configuration correct?
I have tried multiple variants passing the settings, but nothing worked so far.
Thanks